# Python3 SQLite3 Unable to close the database

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to delete a SQLite3 database as a Python script closes (for GDPR) and reload it when the script is run again.

Some of the Python 3 code:

```
connects = sqlite3.connect(path_to_database, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cursors = connects.cursor()

connects = sqlite3.connect(path_to_database, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cursors4 = connects.cursor()

# My code here
cursors.close()
cursors4.close()

#   sqlite3.SQLITE_DETACH   #   these commands do not disconnect the  database
#   sqlite3.SQLITE_DONE
#   sqlite3.SQLITE_DELETE


os.remove(path_to_database)
```

`os.remove(path_to_database)` Produces

```
“Permission Error: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\edtur\\Python_projects\\fix\\fix.db'”

Attempting to delete the database using Explorer also produces an error message
“This action can’t be completed because the file is open in Python”
```

Can someone please tell me how to disconnect/close the database so that I can delete it.

Comment: you need to close both connections the cursors alone is not enough

Comment: Right.  `connects.close()`.

Comment: Hi I do not know if this is the correct way to thank those who responded to my question, but thanks very much.

Comment: Hi I do not know if this is the correct way to thank those who responded to my question, but thanks very much.  Adding the command connects.close()  works but only if one cursor is used.  I will rework my code to only use one cursor. Thanks agin for your valuable help.